# Cannot connect to TCP Socket Listening on user PC (Static IP)

Tags: windows, tcp, network-programming, boost-asio

I am using Boost asio in Visual C++. I am trying to connect to a static IP which listens TCP on port 1222. unfortunately i can only connect with Lan and cannot connect from another Lan to the TCP listening PC(203.143.**.**).

It connects perfectly with the EC2 server. Is it something to do with firewall. but when i run the app it ask for the user to allow firewall for the specific port. I can post my code but i guess it's not something to with the code.

Comment: When failing to connect you should get some kind of error back. Can you edit your question to add the error code? Or at least show the relevant code so we can help you by pointing out where the error checking should be added.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a firewall on the server side (the PC you are trying to connect to) have to be configured to allow incoming connections.
Firewall on your side should be OK, it usually allows any type of outgoing connections.
I don't know what you meant by "the app ask for the user to allow firewall for the specific port" (clarify).

Comment: when the socket starts to listen in an application, a pop up from windows ask us to allow or decline. If we allow it then the socket starts to listen.
Do you mean, if i am trying to open a socket in my application, after installing my application the user manually need to do the firewall config?

Comment: OK, I did not use Winz firewall for a while now, so don't remember it's behaviour.
The computer that will run server (listening) application will have to be accessible from outside of the network it is running on. Yes, it means that this server's network administrators will have to allow incoming connections to this server on specified port.

Comment: Thanks man, If what you are saying is correct, then that could be my problem.